# Atoi function in C?

Tags: c, atoi

```
int atoi(char* s)
{
   int i,n;
   n=0;
   for (i=0; (s[i]>='0') && (s[i]<='9'); i++)
       n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');

   return n;
}
```

In this code what is **s[i]-'0'** doing? Can anyone please explain the detailed working of this function?

Comment: Did you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the table in the link below-

http://www.asciitable.com/

The table is called ASCII Table and it is one of the character-encoding schemes used to represent characters in the binary world.

You can see the decimal numbers 0-9 are represented by numbers 48-57 in the ASCII table. All digits(0-9) are stored as characters.

If your computer stores 48 for decimal number 0, 49 for decimal number 1, 50 for decimal number 2 and so-on. 
Then, to convert a ASCII number into decimal number, you just need to subtract 48 from ASCII number.
For example,

48 - 48 => 0

49 - 48 => 1

50 - 48 => 2

.. and so-on

'0' also represents 48. It is a character form of number 48. That's why, the equation `n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');` has '0'.

Answer (score 1):

> In this code what is `s[i]-'0'` doing?

In C, each **character** like `'0'`, `'A'`, `'+'`, `' '` is assigned a **numeric value** or code.  C requires that the codes for `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'` ...  `'9'` are sequential but does *not* specify their values.

When code performs the below test, it knows that `s[i]` has a value within codes  `'0'` and  `'9'`.  Since these codes are sequential, the *only* values `s[i]` could have are `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'` ...  `'9'`.

```
(s[i]>='0') && (s[i]<='9')
```

By subtracting `'0'` from `s[i]`, code obtains the difference:

```
`0`-'0' --> 0
`1`-'0' --> 1
`2`-'0' --> 2
...
`9`-'0' --> 9
```

Code has successfully translated the character code for an numeric character into a corresponding integer value.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, `s` is a sequence of ASCII encoded characters: a string. <sub>Actually, the encoding does not matter as long as it has the characters `0` through `9` as a sequence.</sub> Let's say it has the value `"123ABC"`, for this explanation.

`n` is the output number. At the start of the function it is initialized to zero.

In the first iteration of the loop we have

```
i=0
s[i] = '1'  (which is encoded as 49, in ASCII)
n = 0
```

so the math is like this:

```
n = n * 10 + (s[i] - '0')
n = 0 * 10 + ('1' - '0')
n = '1' - '0'
```

And converting the character syntax to the ASCII encoding gives this:

```
n = 49 - 48
n = 1
```

In the next iteration we have:

```
i = 1
s[i] = '2' (ASCII 50)
n = 1

n = n * 10 + (s[i] - '0')
n = 1 * 10 + ('2' - '0')
n = 10 + ('2' - '0')
n = 10 + (50 - 48)
n = 10 + 2
n = 12
```

And, in the third iteration:

```
i = 2
s[i] = '3' (ASCII 51)
n = 12

n = n * 10 + (s[i] - '0')
n = 12 * 10 + ('3' - '0')
n = 120 + ('3' - '0')
n = 120 + (51 - 48)
n = 120 + 3
n = 123
```

And, in the final iteration `s[i] = 'A'` which is not in the range specified by the `if` statement, so the loop exits.

As you can see it has correctly converted the string `"123"` to the number `123`.